# Codecademy Advance Python The "In" Operator. Why does key print values?

Tags: python

I am having difficulty understanding why the last line in the code is:

```
print key, my_dict[key]
```

instead of...

```
print key, my_dict[values]
```

CODE

```
my_dict = { 
"Name": "Joshua", 
"Age": "28",
"Nationality": "UK" 

print my_dict.keys()

print my_dict.values()

for key in my_dict: 
    print key, my_dict[key]

}
```

On the last line, we have already said print key, and the instructions say to print the values after printing the key, so why is the code referencing my_dict again and printing (again) [key]. Why does "key" print values?

Comment: You have a syntax error in your code. `}` in last line!

Comment: `my_dict[key]` has nothing to do with the `keys` function, but returns the value associated with the variable `key` from your dict. It seems like you should read up on basic Python syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Lists work like this:

```
foo = ["spam", "spam", "lovely spam"]
print foo[0] # prints "spam"
```

0 is the index for the element "spam".

You are using a dictionary. Dictionaries don't have indexes, they have keys.

```
my_dict = { 
"Name": "Joshua", 
"Age": "28",
"Nationality": "UK" 
}

print my_dict["Name"]
```

In the list at position "0" there is a string "spam".

In the dictionary at position "Name" there is a string "Joshua".

Answer (score 0):

DIctionary is a mapping type.It consists of key value pairs.For each key there will be an associated value.So for retreiving a value associated with a key, we use dict[key].It is just like accessing an element in a list with the index value.In your example if you call `my_dict['name']` you will get  `"Joshua"`